# How to parse JSON data by Json.net when there is a name of special name?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var rootResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LastFMResponse_ArtistTracks>(result);
                return rootResult;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The above string result returns the full json response that looks something like

```
{
"artisttracks": {
"track": [
{
"artist": {
"#text": "Flying Lotus",
"mbid": "fc7376fe-1a6f-4414-b4a7-83f50ed59c92"
},
"name": "Arkestry",
"streamable": "0",
"mbid": "5f2c6783-f876-4bbe-9577-d3498da6b0ab",
"album": {
"#text": "Cosmogramma",
"mbid": "7369257e-2346-4fe6-8810-c92c409d6671"
},
"url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Flying+Lotus/_/Arkestry",
"image": [
{
"#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/50227cde795b4702c7b4d7ddcf0b85ff.png",
"size": "small"
},
{
"#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/50227cde795b4702c7b4d7ddcf0b85ff.png",
"size": "medium"
},
{
"#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/50227cde795b4702c7b4d7ddcf0b85ff.png",
"size": "large"
},
{
"#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/50227cde795b4702c7b4d7ddcf0b85ff.png",
"size": "extralarge"
}
],
"date": {
"uts": "1530728536",
"#text": "04 Jul 2018, 18:22"
}
```

However the DeserializeObject method is not able to deserialize the string into the object that holds a text field instead of the #text one.
The following is my class definition for the DeserializeObject destination.

```
public class LastFMResponse_ArtistTracks
{
        public Artisttracks artisttracks { get; set; }

        public class Artisttracks
        {
            public Track[] track { get; set; }
            public Attr @attr { get; set; }
        }
        public class Attr
        {
            public string user { get; set; }
            public string artist { get; set; }
            public string page { get; set; }
            public string perPage { get; set; }
            public string totalPages { get; set; }
            public string total { get; set; }
        }
        public class Track
        {
            public Artist artist { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string streamable { get; set; }
            public string mbid { get; set; }
            public Album album { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public Image[] image { get; set; }
            public Date date { get; set; }
        }
        public class Artist
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string mbid { get; set; }
        }
        public class Album
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string mbid { get; set; }
        }
        public class Date
        {
            public string uts { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
        }
        public class Image
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string size { get; set; }
        }
 }
```

Am I doing this the improper way or is there a way to get the text?

Comment: Your json data is incorrect in your question.

Comment: The data is incomplete because it was really long, there is an attr part of the json response

Comment: Just to clarify, the deserialize method works perfectly but the public string text fields in rootresult are all empty after the deserialization

Comment: OK!! I write an answer you can try it @michael16574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your JSON data name is `#text`, Default JSON Convert can't bind with `public string text { get; set; }` property

a simple way, you can try to add `JsonProperty` Attribute on `public string text { get; set; }`property.

```
 [JsonProperty("#text")]
 public string text { get; set; }
```

[C# Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZVIoTl)

---

[JsonPropertyAttribut](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm)